# how to send serialized form to webapi Method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

im trying to send my from with ajax( $.post ) to a webApi . ajax request run succesfull but when i send data to method in web api form collection get null then my method return "false"
please help me 
My WebApi Method

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string AddRecord([FromBody]FormCollection form)
    {
        try
        {
            PersonBLL personbll = new PersonBLL();
            var person = new tbl_persons();
            person.firstname = form["txt_namePartial"];
            person.lastname = form["txt_lastnamePartial"];
            person.age = byte.Parse(form["txt_agePartial"]);
            var result = personbll.AddRecord(person);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
```

my Ajax function

```
function AddRecordWithFormCollection(url, callback) {

$.post("/api/Person/AddRecord",JSON.stringify(url) , function (data, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
        hidePreloader();
        unloadDiv("div_operation");
        BindTable();

       //AddRowTable(data, obj.name, obj.lastname, obj.age);
        return callback(data);

    } else {
        alert("Error in Method [AddRecord]");
        hidePreloader();

    }
});
```

}

Comment: try with removing [FromBody]

Comment: What data are your sending (i.e. what is `url`?) And why are you using `FormCollection` insead of binding to your model?

Comment: The problem is related with the `data` you are not sending it from client side..

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the JSON you're sending as `data` (`JSON.stringify(url)`) is of type `FormCollection`.   Also a *webapi* shouldn't be accepting an *asp.net* `formcollection` as they are two different technologies.   Your webapi should be able to be called from anywhere (eg from `curl` or from a windows forms app) which should not need to format the request into an asp.net web forms format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use that :

```
var form = $("#body").find("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: "/api/Person/AddRecord",
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // Do something
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Get a try because I never used the **FormCollection** object type but just a model class.

Comment: I used Ajax you provide to me but i changed FormCollection to FormDataCollection

Comment: Thanks for your sharing ;) Enjoy !

Answer (score -1):

```
This should be:
url=$("#form").serialize();
function AddRecordWithFormCollection(url, callback) {

$.post("/api/Person/AddRecord",url , function (data, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
        hidePreloader();
        unloadDiv("div_operation");
        BindTable();

       //AddRowTable(data, obj.name, obj.lastname, obj.age);
        return callback(data);

    } else {
        alert("Error in Method [AddRecord]");
        hidePreloader();

    }
});

}
```

Comment: please clarify your answer